# How do I calculate MaxQ in Q-learning?

Tags: c++, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I'making a implementation of Q-learning, specifically the Bellman equation.[image: Bellman equation]

I'm using the version from a [website](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/an-introduction-to-q-learning-reinforcement-learning-14ac0b4493cc/) that guides he through the problem, but I have question:
For maxQ, do I calculate the max reward using all Q-table values of the new state (s') - in my case 4 possible action (a'), each with their respective value- or the sum of the Q-table values of all the positions when taking the action (a')?

In other words, do I use the highest Q-value of all the possible actions I can take, or the summed Q-values of all the "neighbouring" squares?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You always use max Q-value for all the possible actions you can take.

The idea is to pick the action with biggest (best) Q-Value of next state in order to stay in optimal policy Qpi* .